# Get numbers after dash "-" from an array and preserve dash in his original position. Regex

Tags: php, html, arrays, regex, numbers

A user from other thread help me to figure out how to get the numbers from an array, but now I can't get the numbers afer "-" dash. Let me show you what I have and put you in situation.

I''ve got an array with the next content:

```
Array(
[0] => <tr><td>29/06/2015</td><td>19:35</td><td>12345 Column information</td><td>67899 Column information - 12</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>
[1] => <tr><td>12/03/2015</td><td>10:12</td><td>98545 Column information</td><td>67659 Column information - 32</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>
[2] => <tr><td>11/02/2015</td><td>12:40</td><td>59675 Column information</td><td>94859 Column information - 11</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>
[3] => <tr><td>01/01/2015</td><td>20:12</td><td>69365 Column information</td><td>78464 Column information - 63</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>
)
```

Finally I know how to get every number (except the number after dash "-"):

```
$re = "/.*?(\\d+)\\s.*?(\\d+)\\s.*/m";
$str = "<tr><td>29/06/2015</td><td>19:35</td><td>12345 Column information</td><td>67899 Column information - 12</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>";
$subst = "$1, $2";
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Here's the $result; output:

```
foreach($result as $finalresult) echo $finalresult.'<br>';

12345,67899
98545,67659
59675,94859
69365,78464
```

What I expected from all this process and cannot figure out is to get the number after dash "-" too:

```
12345,67899-12
98545,67659-32
59675,94859-11
69365,78464-63
```

But this does not end here... when the number after dash "-" is lower than 50 I need to transform the $result output. See the example below.
If the number after "-" < 50 then it needs to be transformed, taking the first digit and putting it at units position. Then the tens position might be zero. 
When is 50 or above, the number ramains as it is. Example:

```
    12345,67899-12 ------> 12345,67899-01
    98545,67659-32 ------> 12345,67899-03
    59675,94859-11 ------> 12345,67899-01
    52375,53259-49 ------> 12345,67899-04
    69365,73464-63 ------> 12345,67899-63
    89765,12332-51 ------> 12345,67899-51
    38545,54213-70 ------> 12345,67899-70
```

And now is when my head explodes!

Beforehand thanks **a lot** for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick for you:

```
$re = '/.*?(\d+)\s.*?(\d+)\s.*?-\s(\d+).*/';
$str = "<tr><td>29/06/2015</td><td>19:35</td><td>12345 Column information</td><td>67899 Column information - 12</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>";
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
if ($matches[3]<50) $matches[3] = floor($matches[3]/10);
$format = '%d,%d-%02d';
$result = sprintf($format, $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3]);
echo $result;
```

Note that I changed your `$re` to be single quoted instead of double quoted for readability, and I'm using `preg_match` instead of `preg_replace` so I can work with the matched patterns.

To explain the regex to you, there are a few things going on:

- `/` is the regex delimiter.
- `.*?`: The `.` tells the regex to match any character. The `*` says to do it zero or more times, and the `?` says to do it in a "lazy" fashion. The plain `.*` at the end of `$re` matches the whole rest of the string.
- `(\d+)`: The `\d` is a wildcard telling the regex to match any digit. The `+` says "one or more times", and the `()` says to capture this. The first `()` surrounded group is `$matches[1]`.
- `\s`: Is a wildcard for any space character.
- `-`: Is the literal `-` character.

Comment: What a clean code, thanks!! I've got an error with preg_match and $str because I'm using an array. Solved it by putting your code inside foreach. This is a good way to fix it? the output is correct, but I don't know if this is the best way to work with preg_match and arrays.

Comment: please can you explain me how $re is exactly working? I'm tying to learn about regular expressions instead of simply copying the code :)

Comment: Regular expressions take a while to wrap your head around. Start by reading the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php), to really get the hang of them, try a [live regex sandbox](https://regex101.com/). I'll add an explanation of `$re` to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm very grateful. Thanks to you I'm learning a lot from regex. I'm making some good progress modifying your code to another similar task. Can I edit this thread and ask you about it or may be better to create another thread with the question?

Comment: You should leave this resolved question as-us, and ask the new question in a new thread.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm going to create a new one :)

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for. I modified your regular expression slightly. The `(.*?<td>){3}` will match anything up to the third `<td>`. The `?P<first>` in the subpattern `(?P<first>\d+)` etc. is called a named subpattern, which makes their value easy to access from the `$matches` array.

```
$a = [
    '<tr><td>29/06/2015</td><td>19:35</td><td>12345 Column information</td><td>67899 Column information - 12</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>12/03/2015</td><td>10:12</td><td>98545 Column information</td><td>67659 Column information - 32</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>11/02/2015</td><td>12:40</td><td>59675 Column information</td><td>94859 Column information - 11</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>',
    '<tr><td>01/01/2015</td><td>20:12</td><td>69365 Column information</td><td>78464 Column information - 63</td><td>Information</td><td>More information</td></tr>',
];

$result = [];

foreach ($a as $row) {
    $p = '#(.*?<td>){3}(?P<first>\d+).*?</td><td>(?P<second>\d+).*?(?P<third>\d+)#';

    if (preg_match($p, $row, $matches)) {
        if ($matches['third'] < 50) {
            $matches['third'] = '0'.$matches['third'][0];
        }
        $result[] =
            $matches['first'] . ',' .
            $matches['second'] . '-' .
            $matches['third'];
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345,67899-01
    [1] => 98545,67659-03
    [2] => 59675,94859-01
    [3] => 69365,78464-63
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much once again!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well... I don't know if it will help, but I made this with RegExr and it fits properly:

(([0-9]+){5})|(- [0-9]{2})

I hope you might find it some use!